# awk: How to use different field separators, and operate on different columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

For multiple files, I'm trying to extract columns containing a specific string, but the field separators in the files are different, and the string will appear in a different column depending on the file.

Example line in file 1 (delimiter is `:`):

```
sss:string1:rrr
```

Example line in file 2 (delimiter is `,`):

```
sss,sss,string321,sss,sss
```

Example line in file 3 (delimiter is `'`):

```
example'e123'string2'lol
```

How could I go about finding "string" in the above three files using `awk` or other command-line tool?

I know that for `file 1` I could perform:

```
awk -F: '$2 ~ /string/ {print $2}'
```

and the output would be:

```
string1
```

yet I want to do this for multiple files with multiple separators and multiple columns, because do each file individually would be very time consuming? Is it possible to do?

Comment: seems what you need is just `grep -Eo 'string[0-9]+' multiple-files*`, don't you?

Comment: You have to know your input in order to tell the computer how to extract it. Since you already know what files have what delimiters, I would just write different scripts that deal with the different files. Why try to combine everything?

Comment: Is it acceptable to assume that a separator is a character of punctuation, whereas the strings you are matching against are (only) alphanumeric?

Comment: "because do each file individually would be very time consuming" – Why? Huge number of tiny files?

Answer (score 4):

Doing 3 separate calls:

```
awk -F: '{print $2}' file1
awk -F, '{print $3}' file2
awk -F\' '{print $3}' file3
```

most likely will be just as fast as something like

```
awk '
    FILENAME == "file1" && FNR == 1 {FS = ":"; col = 2; $0 = $0}
    FILENAME == "file2" && FNR == 1 {FS = ","; col = 3; $0 = $0}
    FILENAME == "file3" && FNR == 1 {FS = "'\''"; col = 3; $0 = $0}
    {print $col}
' file1 file2 file3
```

Certainly the former is easier to read and maintain.

As the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says, simple is better than complex.

Comment: That is a nice approach but it has a serious bug: Assigning a value to `FS` affects the next line only. Thus you are missing the first line of each file. You can correct that by adding `; $0=$0;` after `col = ...`

Comment: Thanks fixed. With GNU awk it would be a good use for a BEGINFILE block

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it one command then the following will work:

`awk -F : '{print $2}' file1 && awk -F : '{print $3}' file2 && awk -F : '{print $3}' file3`

That will output:

```
string1
string321
string2
```

If you just want to print `string` and nothing included with it then:

`awk -F : '{print substr($2,1,6)}' file1 && awk -F , '{print substr($3,1,6)}' file2 && awk -F \' '{print substr($3,1,6)}' file3`

To explain:

`substr($2,1,6)` prints a substring of the 2nd field starting at the 1st position with 6 of the characters for `string`. The output will be

```
string
string
string
```